# How delete image files after unit test finished?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, unit-testing, django-1.11

In unit test I create 3 objects (articles) at the beginning. After test complete I notice that there are 3 images in `media_root` folder.

**Question**: How to delete that images which was created after test finished?

**P.S.** I tried to use next code but it delete `media_root` folder.

```
def tearDown(self):
        rmtree(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, ignore_errors=True)
```

NOTE: Problems in methods `test_article_form_valid` and `test_article_crud`.

**tests.py:**

```
class ArticleTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):  
        self.image = open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images/tests/image.jpg'), "r")

    def test_article_form_valid(self):
        data = {
            'head': 'TEXT',
        }
        files_data = {
            'image': SimpleUploadedFile(
                name=self.image.name,
                content=self.image.read(),
                content_type='image/jpeg'
            )
        }
        form = ArticleForm(data=data, files=files_data)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())  <-- ERROR

    def test_article_crud(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse("article:article_create"))
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("article:article_create"),
            data={
                'head': 'TEST',
                'image': self.image
            },
            follow=True,
            format='multipart'
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(Article.objects.all().count(), 1) <-- ERROR

    def test_article_view(self):
        first_article = Article.objects.create(
            pk=150,
            head='First',
            image=SimpleUploadedFile(
                name=self.image.name,
                content=self.image.read(),
                content_type='image/jpeg'
            )
        )

        second_article = Article.objects.create(
            pk=160,
            head='Second',
            image=SimpleUploadedFile(
                name=self.image.name,
                content=self.image.read(),
                content_type='image/jpeg'
            )
        )

        third_article = Article.objects.create(
            pk=170,
            head='Third',
            image=SimpleUploadedFile(
                name=self.image.name,
                content=self.image.read(),
                content_type='image/jpeg'
            )
        )
        [***]
```

**ERROR**:

```
FAIL: test_article_crud (article.tests.ArticleTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nurzhan/CA/article/tests.py", line 55, in test_article_crud
    self.assertEqual(Article.objects.all().count(), 1)
AssertionError: 0 != 1

======================================================================
FAIL: test_article_form_valid (article.tests.ArticleTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nurzhan/CA/article/tests.py", line 117, in test_article_form_valid
    self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
AssertionError: False is not true
```

Answer (score 10):

I found this [article](https://dirtycoder.net/2016/02/09/testing-a-model-that-have-an-imagefield/) and it worked to me

```
import shutil, tempfile
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings

MEDIA_ROOT = tempfile.mkdtemp()

@override_settings(MEDIA_ROOT=MEDIA_ROOT)
class MeuPetTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls): 
        shutil.rmtree(MEDIA_ROOT, ignore_errors=True)
        super().tearDownClass()
```

Comment: It doesn't work correctly, it creates the files in the new MEDIA_ROOT, yes, but also in the MEDIA_ROOT of the project, at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best solution is to create a directory that will contain a `'/media'` folder, this directory can then be deleted in the tearDown function.

Based on [this article](https://bhch.github.io/posts/2018/12/django-how-to-clean-up-images-and-temporary-files-created-during-testing/), I tried the solution and it worked perfectly. You won't even notice the creation and deletion of the test directory and the files created in your tests won't be in your default media location.

```
from django.test import override_settings
import shutil

TEST_DIR = 'test_data'

class SomeTests(TestCase):
    ...

    # use the `override_settings` decorator on 
    # those methods where you're uploading images

    @override_settings(MEDIA_ROOT=(TEST_DIR + '/media'))
    def test_file_upload(self):
        ...
        # your code
        ...

...


# then create a tearDownModule function
# to remove the `TEST_DIR` folder at the 
# end of tests

def tearDownModule():
    print "\nDeleting temporary files...\n"
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(TEST_DIR)
    except OSError:
        pass
```

If you want to implement this solution in DRF, your code should look like this:

```
from django.test import override_settings
import shutil
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

TEST_DIR = 'test_data'

class SomeTest(APITestCase):
    ...

    # use the `override_settings` decorator on 
    # those methods where you're uploading images
    
    # do this if any logic exists to create files
    # in your setUp
    @override_settings(MEDIA_ROOT=(TEST_DIR + '/media'))
    def setUp(self):
        ...
        # your code
        ...

    @override_settings(MEDIA_ROOT=(TEST_DIR + '/media'))
    def test_file_upload(self):
        ...
        # your code
        ...

    def tearDown(self):
        print "\nDeleting temporary files...\n"
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(TEST_DIR)
        except OSError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tempfile` module in python, use it as `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` in the `TestCase` `setUp()` method,

```
from django.conf import settings
import tempfile

def setUp(self):
    settings.MEDIA_ROOT = tempfile.mkdtemp()
```

<s>Then, the files created in the test will be automatically removed when the test is finished.</s>

**UPDATE**:

Then, the files created in the test will not be automatically removed when the test is finished, so do not forget to delete the temporary directory after finishing the test.

Comment: But the OP wants to retain the directory, just remove the files from within it, I think.

Comment: @SiHa absolutely right! I need delete only image files which was created in my test. Dont touch to folder. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: The point of testing is to mock a certain functionality without affecting the actual database and testing, isn't it? If you use `tempfile` module you don't have to create actual image objects, but create a mock for them and do your testing then after the test, the objects will automatically deleted. There doesn't even arise a question about removing the files, there are no files created, on run time they are created and destroyed.

Comment: @zaidfazil your code raise error in other my test. I update my post with error message and some code. Can you check it pls again. Do you have ideas why I have such errors after your code?

Comment: You did not add my code in the `setUp()` method of your `TestCase`, add `settings.MEDIA_ROOT = tempfile.mkdtemp()` in your `setUp()` method. Then give it a try.

Comment: Also, the `content_type` argument in `SimpleUploadedFile` should be `content_type='multipart/form-data'`, because, you are testing a form input.

Comment: I test your code but unfortunately it didn't help me =(

Comment: **"the files created in the test will be automatically removed when the test is finished"** this is not true. The docs state that [The user of mkdtemp() is responsible for deleting the temporary directory and its contents when done with it.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp)

Comment: Sorry man. Totally misunderstood. Thank you for letting me realise the mistake. Appreciate the support and help.

Answer (score 0):

For me best solution was to write a function which delete images and add it into test class tearDown method.

```py
def delete_test_image():
    images_path = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media/images')
    files = [i for i in os.listdir(images_path) 
             if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(images_path, i))
             and i.startswith('test_image_')]

    for file in files:
        os.remove(os.path.join(images_path, file))
```